# How to connect pentaho BI to an H2 database?

Tags: pentaho, h2

For the life of me I can't get pentaho BI to connect to my h2 datasource.

```
Current configuration:

Database Type: H2 Native (JDBC)  
Host Name: localhost  
Database Name: /home/myusername/h2/pemc_for_pentaho  
Port Number: 3306  
Username: sa  
Password: sa
```

I'm sure my mistake is with the Database Name. If it helps, in tomcat's catalina.out I'm getting this:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error opening database: "Could not load properties /home/clim/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/bin/h2:/localhost:3306/ho
>   me/clim/h2/pemc_for_pentaho.lock.db" [8000-131]

Please help before I lose all my hair over this.